# adding a background image to a ui collection view

Tags: ios, user-interface, ipad

I am new to iOS development and I was wondering how do I add a background image that will repeat vertically to my UI Collection View that I have created to display an array of images?

Comment: Try `collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage"]];`

Comment: Would I just put that in my .m file for the View Controller?

Comment: Yup, in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.pnd"]];
}
```

Comment: How do you clip it to the bottom of the screen?!

Answer (score 34):

This will work as well and I think is more correct than the work around with the background color. Go for the **backgroundView** directly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];

}
```

Comment: How isn't this the selected answer?

Answer (score 4):

For swift, add to viewDidLoad():

```
    self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)
```

Comment: How do you clip it to the bottom of the screen?!

Comment: I found it necessary to remove my previous background color setting in the storyboard, before the pattern image became visible.