# Swift how to make a background like in this image?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a background like in this image [image]

So i have created an image 
[image]

And here is my code

```
let background_image: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backg")
    view.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    return view
}()

background_image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
background_image.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
background_image.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
background_image.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
```

But the problem is because the screen height is bigger than the width,is makes image looks expanded in height,like this
[image]

How can i make image to only fill the width of the screen not the height?

Comment: change  view.contentMode = .scaleToFill to  view.contentMode = .aspectFill

Comment: Or use an image whose aspect ratio is at least as narrow as the narrowest iPhone, then use `.top`. Also, it's `.scaleAspectFill` now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the colorWithPatternImage method (see below)?

```
UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluewhite.png"];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage];
```

In Swift 3, it looks like this:

```
var patternImage = UIImage(named:"bluewhite.png")
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: patternImage!)
```

But for an array or a group of images you can use a Collection View behind your main view and configure the background of each collection view item like this:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorWithPatternImage:patternImage!)
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789983/adding-a-background-image-to-a-ui-collection-view) which discusses a similar issue.

Comment: Do you think the collection view approach (discussed above) will work for you? Also, can you break up each of the images into separate png files and put them in a array rather than presenting them stitched together as one image?

Comment: i don't use group of images so i don't think so

Answer (score 0):

```
view.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

should be

```
view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```